# GIT: merge two branches into a new one without dependencies in Gerrit

Tags: git, merge, branch, gerrit

I have two branches in my local repo: **branch_1** and **branch_2**, each is based on the same commit **A** and contains several commits (heads are **A1** and **A2** correspondingly).

I pushed both of **A1** and **A2** to Gerrit **master** branch and have two separate reviews.
Then, I abandoned them.

Now I need to create a new local branch **branch_3** based on **A** and containing changes from both **A1** and **A2** into **A3**. I did:

`git checkout -b branch_3 origin/master`

`git merge branch_1 branch_2`

I have got a commit **A3** that I need and pushed it to Gerrit.
A third review was created, but it depended on two previous abandoned commits, therefore I cannot submit it.

Is there any way to merge two branches into one commit **A3** so that it depends on only **A** but not **A1** and **A2**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option '-n' should be used for cherry-pick for each necessary commit:

```
git checkout A
git cherry-pick -n A1
git cherry-pick -n A2
git commit
```

A newly created commit A3 is the expected one.

Answer (score 2):

approach 1: try [rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) the branch which contains A3 onto `origin/master`

approach 2: checkout a clean branch, cherry-pick commit A3, and push again:

`git checkout -b feature --track origin/master`

`git cherry-pick A3`

`git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

Comment: Cherry-picking failed with the following error:

`error: Commit 3a6bba4e6f216bb43f4d01da0f7175bd67ac8fa3 is a merge but no -m option was given.`

`fatal: cherry-pick failed`